# C#.NET: Class or Collection with a maximal and defined set of fields, but with dynamic returns of fields

Tags: c#, .net, oop

Okay, what do I need?

I'm looking for a class (object by schema instance), which has a maximal number of hard defined fields. And a dynamic way to "use" (create, read, update, delete) a "sub-object" of it.

Like this:

```cs
public class Books
{
   public int Id;
   public string Title;
   public string Isbn;
   public int Pages;
   public int Price;
   public string Author;
   public string DescriptionSmall;
   public string DescriptionLong;
   public string Publisher;

   //create constructor:
   public Books(int id, string title, string isbn, ...) {
      Id = id,
      Title = title,
      Isbn = isbn,
      ...
    //only the setted fields should be usable
   }

   //add fields (only pre-defined should be possible)
   public void|bool Add(Dictionary<string, object>) { //or List<> overload for only field names (without values)
      //add fields 
   }

   //get a return (only pre-defined should be possible)
   public void|bool return Get(Dictionary<string, object>) {
      //return as a sub-object
   }

   //delete void|bool fields
   public Delete(Dictionary<string, object>) {
      //delete fields
   }

   //update fields
   public Update(...) {
      ...
   }
}

//and than I can use it like a object, createtd by instance or what ever. :/
var smallBooks = new Books(id = 1, Title = "Lord of tha weed"); //can use all methods but for the moment only the created fields, but can add more fields by add()...
```

I dislike to have hunderds of models/entites for all possible field-combinations.

The problem is, that I try to update a database via GraphQL server.

Is there a way to return a part of the object, which is a "sub-" object, itself?

Yeah I know, I also can create a dynamic obejct with help by ExpandoObject or create a Collection/Dictionary to send.

It's important, that the not used fields are not only NULL, because some fields in my database are nullable and can work with NULL as a value.

-------------------------[Addition: 2021-07-27]-------------------------

Okay, I obviously expressed myself ambiguously. I have a table in the DB and the fields in it are firmly defined. When updating data, however, I only need a few fields from the complete list of all fields. The problem, I would like to keep the selection of the fields dynamic instead of having to create numerous entities or DTOs as part of the main model.

I'm looking for a simple way to create a dynamic sub-object in the code that contains the same methods, but only a (freely selectable) selection of the total fields.

Within my project it happens from time to time that data should be collected and processed before that data is finally sent to the server as a dynamic subset, e.g. as an update (GraphQL update mutation). An existing data set (main model) should, as it were, reflect the current status of the database. But only individual fields are required for an update.

I just want to avoid having to create countless classes for all combinations and choices.

Is there a way to derive a dynamic partial selection from the main class, which, for example, only contains 1 to x fields, but possibly has a reference to the main class and its fields (sync). - So an instance from the main class and dynamically derive further sub-objects from this object.

I used to simply create a `dictionary<string, object>` with field names and values ​​and use `mainDict.GetKeys()` or `mainDict.Select(f => f.key / f.value)` from this selection in a complex method to create a "small copy" to update only separate fields (via uploading to the server). - But I'd like to use oop with classes, instances and maybe dynamic objects (expando objects). - But I don't know how. ;) Sorry.

I'm open to any suggestion. If possible, simple and with little code, but as dynamic as possible.

Comment: Your comments aren't clear.  On one hand, you say you want to add any number of fields, but on the other you keep referencing "pre-defined".  Which is it?  Pre-defined where?

Comment: Most likely what you want is to extend DynamicObject yourself.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you would like to have a dynamic list of fields that can expand the number of fields on the class and also be able to store that in a database. The only way I can think of is to create a FieldEntity which has some unique properties (like type, multiselect for drop-down, etc but most important also a 'Name' and  'Value' property. Create a one-to-many relation between the two and you have what you want.

Comment: I'd approach it from a different angle - what about giving the properties a getter&setter which actually write the name of the property in a Hashset if it was set. Than later on look into the Hashset to see which properties were set. Not sure if this matches your use case. An ORM like Entity Framework has change tracking included, not sure if it can be combined with GraphQL.

Comment: @PaulSinnema - I think the OP is trying to say that he has a class with normal fields/properties and he only wants to populate a subset of all of the fields available and he wants to distinguish between a field that is NULL because that's the value in the database and MISSING because it was not in the subset of the populated fields.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment. A more complex would be like this:

[image]

In this example the Course has some fixed number of fields but expands on that using the CouresField (many-to-many) connection to connect several FormFields. The FieldValue entity holds the values for the fields in combination with the UserFieldValue (many-to-many) for each user (in this case).

Now maintaining all of this is a lot of work but you can use the EntityFramework to maintain the many-to-many connections for you. No need to do all the coding yourself. It will be automatically generated.

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned that above too:

I have a server (C # .NET-5 GraphQL api with database connection) and a client (C # .NET-4.5 command line application).

The server was previously a REST API and is now a GraphQL API with endpoints and a db connection.

The client connects a partner API (pull data response) with my server API (GraphQL) to synchronize those data sets. The client is called via CronJob, every 15 minutes.